# How to solve find_element_by_class_name() throwing "Unable to find element with class name '...'"?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

The webpage (see `driver.get()` below) seems to have one table with class name as table. I can't seem to locate it using the code below.

I was under the impression that I could locate these type of Javascript elements using Selenium.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.quit()
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get('http://investsnips.com/list-of-publicly-traded-micro-cap-diversified-biotechnology-and-pharmaceutical-companies/')


content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.table')
x = driver.find_element_by_class_name("table")
```

I'm getting this error (content nor x work)

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'table'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"94","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:49464","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"value\": \"table\", \"sessionId\": \"a988f310-65da-11e7-a655-01f6986e9e41\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/a988f310-65da-11e7-a655-01f6986e9e41/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: Which element are you exactly trying to locate?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML fragment (extraced via the development tools; F12) to your question by editiing. The link is volatile and your question will be useless if the link changes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table in in iframe. You have to switch iframe before finding the table. See code below.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get('http://investsnips.com/list-of-publicly-traded-micro-cap-diversified-biotechnology-and-pharmaceutical-companies/')

#Find the iframe tradingview_xxxxx and then switch into the iframe
iframeElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[id*="tradingview_"]')
driver.switch_to_frame(iframeElement)
#Wait for the table
waitForPresence = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
waitForPresence.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'table.table'))
theTable = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.table')
```

Comment: I see. Going to run some tests on you code. Thank you so much  =)

Comment: Hi,  Are you importing something for the `wait` in `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'table.table'))`.   I don't see any `wait` variable assignments in your code.